# Show category description in shop grid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’d like to be able to display the category description for each of the categories in our shop – both parent and child – either in an overlay below the h4 category title or underneath.

Our theme has a filter which governs this layout, and any attempts I’ve made to adapt it and add an additional div or span by including **echo category_description()** inside the h4 title tags has been unsuccessful - [https://www.epianos.co.uk/digital-pianos/][1]

```
<div class="category-grid-item">
                        <a class="category-img" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $c->slug, 'product_cat' ) ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $c->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                                $image        = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'large' );
                                $image        = isset( $image[0] ) ? $image[0] : wc_placeholder_img_src();
    
            
                            if ( isset( $image ) ) {
                                ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $c->name ); ?>" />
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </a>
                        <h4 class="category-title">
                            <?php echo esc_html( $c->name ); ?><span class="count"><?php echo esc_attr( $c->count ); ?></span>
                        </h4>       
                            
                </div>


  [1]: https://www.epianos.co.uk/digital-pianos/
```

Comment: Is this a working part of your code or not? Can you give us your non-working version? How do you print the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the category id to the **category_description** function

from [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_description/):

```
category_description( int $category )
Retrieves category description.

$category (int) (Optional) Category ID. Defaults to the current category ID.
```

Your code should be as follows:

```html
<h4 class="category-title">
  <?php echo esc_html( $c->name ); ?> <?php echo category_description( $c->term_id ); ?>
  <span class="count"><?php echo esc_attr( $c->count ); ?></span>
</h4>
```